# Deleting specific cell in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

Been looking for a way to delete a specif cell in an excel sheet using python.
The only thing I found is deleting an entire row or colum.
For example: if the cell contains the word 'null' than the script will delete this cell entirley.
Thanks

Comment: What library are you using? `xlwings`, `openpyxl`?

Comment: Maybe it's x\y problem. What is the purpose of having this excel file, where does it comes from, and why do you need to remove the null?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.